# Errors posting post REQUEST in thunder client

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I make a post REQUEST in thunder client I can't get my data back in response but I get 500 internal server error, this is the error that I got the posting request in thunder client or postman

```
{
    "code": 79,
    "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
    "errInfo": {
        "writeConcern": {
            "w": "majority;",
            "wtimeout": 0,
            "provenance": "clientSupplied"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "n": 1,
        "opTime": {
            "ts": {
                "$timestamp": "7022899934215012355"
            },
            "t": 99
        },
        "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000063",
        "ok": 1,
        "writeConcernError": {
            "code": 79,
            "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
            "errmsg": "No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration",
            "errInfo": {
                "writeConcern": {
                    "w": "majority;",
                    "wtimeout": 0,
                    "provenance": "clientSupplied"
                }
            }
        },
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": {
                "$timestamp": "7022899934215012355"
            },
            "signature": {
                "hash": "/gnrM/bYkyRYi4XXXmEnkaLJJpg=",
                "keyId": {
                    "low": 1,
                    "high": 1620408145,
                    "unsigned": false
                }
            }
        },
        "operationTime": {
            "$timestamp": "7022899934215012355"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and put this code which contain ( writeConcern )in my schema  and it works

const schema = new Schema({
name: String
}, {
writeConcern: {
w: 'majority',
j: true,
wtimeout: 1000
}
});

another thing I did I removed a single quotes that was around my db url

checkout this https://pretagteam.com/question/mongowriteconcernerror-no-write-concern-mode-named-majority-found-in-replica-set-configuration